# How can I create multiple children using one parent with 2D array for UNIX using pipes and fork only?

Tags: c, linux, pipe, fork

I'm trying to write code that creates N processes 1, 2, 3, 4, ..., N for
UNIX (using `fork()`), where N is given by the user. The
processes can be created in any order.
Each process must print indefinitely the order in which
was created, its process id, as well as its serial number
message it prints.
Process messages must be printed alternately, in order
in which the processes were created.
Only using `pipes()` and fork() .The program will
terminates when the user types `Ctrl-C`

How can I synchronize my processes properly?

**Here is my code : **

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int pd[2]; 
    int p; 
    int i; 
    int N;
    int x=0;       
     
    printf("Give me the number of the processes: ");
    scanf("%d", &N);
    for(i=0; i<=N; i++)
        p=fork();
    if (p==0)
    {      
        close(pd[1]);        
        for(i=0; i<N; i++)
        {
            pipe(pd);
            printf("Proccess child %d has Process id_ %d ,message %d\n", i,getpid(),x+1);
            sleep(1); 
            write (pd[1], &x ,sizeof(x));
            read (pd[0] , &x ,sizeof(x)) ; 
            x++;
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        close(pd[0]);
        for(i=0; i<N-1; i++)
            sleep(1); 
    }
    
    return(0);
}
```

This is my terminal:

[terminaloutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RK6E.png)

How can I create multiple processes and print them out like that
ex. if Ν=3, terminal output:

```
Process 1 has process id_1, message 1
Process 2 has process id_2, message 1
Process 3 has process id_3, message 1
Process 1 has process id_1, message 2
Process 2 has process id_2, message 2
Process 3 has process id_3, message 2
Process 1 has process id_1, message 3
Process 2 has process id_2, message 3
Process 3 has process id_3, message 3
```

Comment: Are you sure that you've understood the task correctly? `pipe`s are usually used to send information _between_ processes but you let each child send to itself. I would guess that the parent process would be sending and/or receiving to/from all the children.

Comment: Here's an example of what I mean: https://godbolt.org/z/oE5eGfdn5

Comment: What happens when you read from a pipe when there's no data waiting to be read?